# I want to change the status of JOIN button to "JOINED" when string is matched from the list of strings retrieved from firestore?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to set the Join Button text to Joined if i get the Strings Matched from List. The problem is else loop is also getting executed which i don't want.

Here is my code

> Java

```
   public void JoinBtnState(ContestModel model, ContestViewHolder holder, long totalSlot) {

        String currUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        String MatchID = model.getMatchID();

        CollectionReference collectionReference = fStore.collection("users").document(currUser).collection("ContestJoined");

          //fetching matchlist and contest list
                collectionReference.addSnapshotListener((value, error) -> {
                    if (!value.isEmpty()) {
                        DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot;
                        List<DocumentSnapshot> MatchList = value.getDocuments();
                        for (int i = 0; i < MatchList.size(); i++) {
                            documentSnapshot = MatchList.get(i);
                            String MatchListID = documentSnapshot.getId();
                            if (MatchID.equals(MatchListID)) {
                                System.out.println("FOUND MATCH !"+MatchID+"===="+MatchListID);
                                holder.joinButton.setText("JOINED");
                                holder.joinButton.setEnabled(false);
                                break;
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("ELSE METHOD CALLED !"+MatchID);
                                holder.joinButton.setText("JOIN");
                                holder.joinButton.setEnabled(true);
                            }

                        }

                    } else {
                        holder.joinButton.setText("JOIN");
                        holder.joinButton.setEnabled(true);
                        System.out.println("EMPTY 1 !");
                    }


                });

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to:

- Check if a certain value exists in a list.
- Set a UI element based on the result of that.

In that case it's easiest to separate the check and the UI update. Something like this:

```
DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot;
List<DocumentSnapshot> MatchList = value.getDocuments();
bool isInList = false;
for (int i = 0; i < MatchList.size(); i++) {
    documentSnapshot = MatchList.get(i);
    String MatchListID = documentSnapshot.getId();
    if (MatchID.equals(MatchListID)) {
        isInList = true;
    }
}
if (isInList) {
    System.out.println("FOUND MATCH !"+MatchID+"===="+MatchListID);
    holder.joinButton.setText("JOINED");
    holder.joinButton.setEnabled(false);
} else {
    System.out.println("ELSE METHOD CALLED !"+MatchID);
    holder.joinButton.setText("JOIN");
    holder.joinButton.setEnabled(true);
}
```

---

Unrelated to that: I find it a bit more readable to loop over the results of a query by using the code from the Firebase documentation on [listening to multiple documents in a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection):

```
bool isInList = false;
for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : value) {
    if (MatchID.equals(doc.getId()) {
        isInList = true;
    }
}
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! Code works, just need to remove the 'break' from the if statement.

Comment: Great ! Thanks for your help.